# How to pass custom data to Jasmine or a Reporter?

Tags: jasmine

I have some Protractor tests using Axe (AxeBuilder) like the following:

```
var AxeBuilder = require('path_to_the/axe-webdriverjs');

describe('Page under test', function() {
    'use strict';

    it('should be accessible', function() {
        AxeBuilder(browser.driver).analyze(function(results) {
            expect(results.violations.length).toBe(0);
        });
    });

});
```

How would I go about passing `results.violations` out to Jasmine so that it can be reported in my Jasmine Reporter?

I am currently looking to use the following Jasmine JSON Reporter:

https://github.com/DrewML/jasmine-json-test-reporter

But I will eventually customise this to output HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix for this in the end.

It turns out that the solution is to write a custom Jasmine matcher, like this: http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/custom_matcher.html

This allows you to control what information is passed out to the `result.message`.

Comment: unfortunately, for passed expectations, the `result.message` is always **Passed.** even after custom message in reporter, at least in jasmine 3.10